# Indexing for multilanguage site

Tags: search-engine-indexing, multilingual, localization

I have two language on my site and I'm using multipage vue. I have nl and tr language and I have an index page for who enter except Turkey and Netherlands countries. My pages like this;

Index(for other countries)  -  /

Index-NL (for Netherlands) - /nl/

Index-TR (for Turkey) - /tr/

When publish my website I saw just index page. Other pages not indexing by country location. For example  I'm searching my site in Turkey but I saw Index page instead index-tr on google.

I put code on html for indexing by language

```
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl" href="https://mywebsite.com/nl/" />
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="tr" href="https://mywebsite.com/tr/" />
  <link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://mywebsite.com/" />
```

Also I've redirected on aws by connect location.

So what's the problem here? What I am doing wrong? How can I index properly?